# How to add bootstrap 4 gem to a rails 4.2.5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add bootstrap 4 (alpha) to a rails 4.2.5 project.  I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails), but currently when I load the default route in a web browser I do not see any bootstrap styling nor do I see any stlyesheets being loaded when I view the source.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.3.2'

# tooltips and popovers depend on tether
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
end
```

**application.scss**

```
/*
Custom bootstrap variables must be set or import before bootstrap itself. */
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require tether
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

When I view the source for **index.html.erb** it looks like the following,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>t-shirts</title>


  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="NZZvjurwYoeAsoqrSdIkwLAHHhEnmEep3pkf5WX7SCWZdAiHPPFOv4ntvCuQjm67QtI0vvWBjR8sv4jv6XaEaA==" />
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what shows the html code for `stylesheet` and `javascript`? which ones are included?

Comment: I just amended my question.

Comment: seems that the bootstrap files isn't pick up by the rails, try fix `sprockes-rails` to  `2.3.2` version, then bundle install and restart your server to make the files available through the pipeline.

Comment: thanks, I just tried what you suggested, but I'm still getting the same results as posted above.

Comment: what is the `//= bootstrap`?

Comment: For Bootstrap4Alpha you don't use `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";`, only `@import "bootstrap";` and make sure you've run **bundler**. Also, `btn btn-default navbar-btn`, none of these are Alpha4 classes, these are Bootstrap3 classes. Also, it looks like your application.scss has everything commented out.

Comment: I meant not css but js section require. where is the `require` word?

Comment: please set up exactly according the manual here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I just amended my question with suggestions made in the comments, but I'm still getting the same results as posted before.

Comment: You have tags inside your `application.html.erb` linking to your CSS/JS right? Because even if the files are empty (no css rules etc) you should still see the links if you inspect in the browser. Something like -> `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` and `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` should be inside your `application.html.erb`.

Comment: @vanburen yes that was the problem.